# Add new Locale on android 2.2 HTC Wildfire phone

Tags: languages, htc-wildfire, localization

I entered a competition and won an HTC Wildfire. However it's branded french. i've changed the language to English, but under 'Select Language' it says 'English (France)'. Several apps also tend to think i'm in france some of the time.

How can i add/change the locale to be whatever english is normally for a United Kingdom phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest method is probably to install a UK ROM.  If you don't want to root or use a custom ROM, you can probably find a stock one.  I recommend searching XDA.

Comment: Hmm, was hoping to avoid rooting / flashing my wildfire but if that's the only option then that's what i'll do! Thanks for the info.

Answer (score -1):

Install [Set Locale and Language](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bruce.setlocale), [Locale selector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rfh.localeselector), or other related apps from Google Play!